# Computation tree logic and Kripke structures

Tags: logic, model-checking, temporal-logic, computation-tree-logic

Specifications in [Kripke structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_structure_%28model_checking%29) are verified by Computation tree logic (CTL). However, refering to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic) the CTL-operators are relative to a *current state*. So, when we want to verify if `EF q` is satisfied in a Kripke structure

Do we only need to check if `EF q` holds starting from the starting state oder do we need to check if `EF q` holds starting from every state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTL formulas are always evaluated from the starting state of the Kripke structure. Indeed, CTL stands for computation *Tree* logic, and the tree in question is the unwinding of the Kripke structure, starting from the initial state.

If you want to specify that $EF q$ should hold from every (reachable) state, that can be specified as $AGEFq$, which is still a CTL formula.